# Ethers.js Contract Factories

Tags: javascript, ethereum, polygon, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I'm trying to make a ContractFactory on ethers.js and deploy the smart contract on Polygon's testnet Mumbai through Alchemy.

I have a problem with the deploy function as in the [docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract-factory/) it isn't clear how to format arguments.

As Alchemy docs I have to specify `gasLimit` and `gasPrice`, but I also want to specify custom arguments for my contract's constructor.

The errors that I  get:

- if I put in the deploy function just the parameters of the constructor it says that I didn't specified the `gasLimit` and `gasPrice` parameters
- if I put in the deploy function the parameters of the constructor and `gasLimit` and `gasPrice` I have a problem with the smart contract's constructor because of the parameter's order.
- If I put just `gasLimit` and `gasPrice` it deploys correctly but I don't have the custom smart contract that I want as there are the constructor's parameters missing;

this is the piece of code that deploys the smart contract:

```
const price_unit = "gwei";
const contractFile = await fs.readFileSync('artifacts/contracts/Midly.sol/NFTCollectible.json');
const contract = JSON.parse(contractFile.toString());

const provider = new ethers.providers.AlchemyProvider("maticmum", process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY);
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY, provider);
const price = ethers.utils.formatUnits(await provider.getGasPrice(), price_unit);

const factory = new ethers.ContractFactory(contract.abi, contract.bytecode, wallet);

const deployedContract = await factory.deploy({
  gasLimit: 2,
  gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits(price, price_unit),
}, tokenURI, maxQuantity, cost)
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the constructor arguments first, and the `overrides` object last.

```
const deployedContract = await factory.deploy(tokenURI, maxQuantity, cost, {
  gasLimit: 2,
  gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits(price, price_unit),
})
```

Docs: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract-factory/#ContractFactory-deploy

Comment: This will return 0. If i do a deploy of deploy(0,0,0) at least it can still estimate the fees instead of returning 0. What does maxQuantity and cost refer to ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @CodeGuru If the value of `deployedContract` is 0, then the contract was not deployed. Possibly a misconfiguration in your config, the deploying transaction was not signed with private key corresponding to the deploying transaction sender address, network issue, the constructor threw an exception effectively reverting the deployment, ... In this case, `maxQuantity` and `cost` are parameters passed to the Solidity contract constructor. I included them in the answer because they are included in the question, however I don't know the OP's Solidity code, so I'm not sure what exactly they refer to.